# Selfhosting a WCF service over Https

Tags: wcf, ssl, https, hosting

I want to write a WCF service (self-hosted) that should use https.
By searching the web I found a blog article from msdn that tells me
to use the "netsh.exe" command to bind the certificate to the endpoint 
by commandline:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/10/selfhosting-a-wcf-service-over-https.aspx

However, is this still state of the art?
Why not use this:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicecredentials.servicecertificate(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicecredentials.servicecertificate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Or do I miss something?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Really Nobody? Do I really need to bind the Certificate to a port by commandline (netsh)? Seems that the SetCertificate is not enough to create a https connection.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found out why I need to use the netsh command:

Check this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> From this article:
>   **If the transport is HTTP** (using the WSHttpBinding), SSL over HTTP provides the transport-level security. **In that case, you must
>   configure the computer hosting the service with an SSL certificate
>   bound to a port, as shown later in this topic.** If the transport is
>   TCP (using the NetTcpBinding), by default the transport-level security
>   provided is Windows security, or SSL over TCP. When using SSL over
>   TCP, you must specify the certificate using the SetCertificate method,
>   as shown later in this topic.

So you can only use the Property for tcp binding. 
If you use ssl over http, you need to bind a certificate to a port by netsh command