# WCF Service over HTTPS without IIS, with SSL Certificate from CERT and KEY strings or files

Tags: c#, wcf

I've done work with WCF before - but since it was for in-house use only, not accessable from the internet at all, i just used net.tcp and not cared much about security.

However, i am now in pre-production for a project that will be made availlable over the internet to customers, so security must be planed for.

I've been doing some research on the matter, and from what i gathered (correct me if I am wrong here), HTTPS is my best bet, as HTTP isn't secured at all (by default) and net.tcp could find problems with some firewalls.

Howerer, I don't want to force customers to have to install IIS in their servers if they don't want to, so the plan is to use a self hosted Windows Service. However, i can't seem to find any information on how to setup the server to use HTTPS without na IIS.

1. I found information about using `makecert` and `httpcfg set ssl` to add a new certificate to the store and then set it to a port - that's ok for testing but i'm not seeing this feaseable in the customer's server - not to mention this means i'll be using aself signed certificate - again ok for testing, not so much in production
2. I also found information ([ServiceCredentials MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.servicecredentials.servicecertificate?view=netframework-4.7.2)) about using something like

   ```
   sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
       StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My,
       X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, 
       "af1f50b20cd413ed9cd00c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6");
   ```

to set a certificate that is already in the server's certificate store - that would almost be ok - it still require the customer to know how to manage certificates in the store, not perfect but ok. However i couldn't get it to work - i don't get any error starting the servisse, but if i try to go to the service address in a browser i get na error regarding TLS beeing out of date - Q1: Any idea what could be the problem here?

Q2: Is it possible to have a configuration somewhere where the customer could input the has or at least location for the cert and key files one gets when buying a certificate and use that to secure the service?

Comment: Perhaps this article will be helpful. [Selfhosting a WCF service over Https](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24158884/9014308), [How to: Use Transport Security and Message Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-transport-security-and-message-credentials), [WCF service self hosting with https](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18579541/9014308)

Comment: Thanks @kunif - will look into those articles to see if ifind any info i didn't find elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Q1: As mentioned in the errors, there may be a problem in your certificate. be sure that the certificate is valid(self signed certificate can not expire).
Q2: As far as I know, we could save the certificate as a file(pfx, cert) or install the certificate in the certificate store(certlm.msc, certmgr.msc) in order to manage.
Do you want to host the WCF service over https in windows service project? I have made a demo, wish it is useful to you.
**Service1.cs**

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
        {
            public Service1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:1017");
            ServiceHost sh = null;
            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
                try
                {
                    ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri);
                    sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                    smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                    if (smb == null)
                    {
                        smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                        {
                            HttpsGetEnabled=true,
                        };
                        sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                    }
                    Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding();
                    sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");
                    sh.Open();
                    WriteLog($"Service is ready at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss")}");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    WriteLog(e.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }

            protected override void OnStop()
            {
                if (sh!=null&&sh.State==CommunicationState.Opened)
                {
                    sh.Close();
                    WriteLog($"Service is closed at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss")}");
                }
            }

            public static void WriteLog(string text)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Mylog.txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(text);
                    sw.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        [ServiceContract(Namespace = "mydomain")]
        public interface IService
        {
            [OperationContract]
            string SayHello();
        }
        public class MyService : IService
        {
            public string SayHello()
            {
                Service1.WriteLog(string.Format("Wow, I have been called at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss")));
                return "Hello stranger";
            }
    }
```

**ProjectInstaller.cs**
[image]
[image]
**Install the windows service(administrator privilege CMD)**
[image]
**Bind the certificate to the application port.**
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-sslcert
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate
Certhash parameter specifies the thumbprint of the certificate. The appid parameter is a GUID that can be used to identify the owning application(open the project.csproj file)

```
<ProjectGuid>{56FDE5B9-3821-49DB-82D3-9DCE376D950A}</ProjectGuid>
```

**Start the windows service.**
[image]
**Test(Server Ip is 10.157.13.70):**
[image]
 
**Client invocation(there is a step that validates the server certificate by default)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
        try
        {
            var result = client.SayHello();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Result**
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Regarding Q1 - if i setup that certificate using IIS and then attach my service to the domain it works - so am pretty sure the certificate is ok - i just dont want to depend on IIS

Comment: Ill test your Q2 answer later and let you know if it worked

Comment: Try to configure the TLS version used in communication.
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
And please refer to my way that binding the certificate to the application port.

Comment: Ok -this is what I mentioned in 1. in my question . except i mentioned `httpcfg` and you mention `netsh`. While `netsh` iswhat you'd use in Windows Vista and above, `httpcfg` is what you'd use in Windows Server 2003 and above. This is ok for testing/debugging but what about production - Where i don't know if the customer has Windows Server or not?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It’s the only feasible way I know to accomplish binding the certificate to the port. I see below that the certificate is not bound to the port.
Netsh http show sslcert|findstr portnumber